# Text overlap with Bootstrap 3 on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If you look at [this website](https://ericnuss.com/) in Google Chrome's developer options, specifically mobile responsive toggle, it will overlap my portfolio section over my about section. I have tried a number of potential fixes from the internet, like changing the "display" and "positioning" in CSS. None of those worked.

As a side note this issue doesn't exist on local environment, only live.

Any suggestions?

P.S. This is a portfolio website. I'm not trying to solicit my information. It's just broken and looks bad on mobile. THANKS!

Comment: Add the relevent code here so that we can have a look at it!

Answer (score 0):

Well, try to removing the rule `height: 100%;` from the following classes:

- .intro-section
- .about-section
- .portfolio-section

This solves the overlaping bug. You can still add a media query to reduce the padding-top from all sections.  Something like that:

```
@media all and (max-width: 580px) {
  .about-section, .portfolio-section {
      padding-top: 70px;
  }
}
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the height: 100% from the body. This will allow the body to overflow, and not to stuck to the window's height maximum.